# load video stream from ip camera using a config JSON file in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I m trying to play a video stream in python using opencv with this code. I want to load the stream link using a json file for dynamic purpose.

```
data = open("room-out-config.json","r")
data = json.load(data)
camera = data['camera']
write = data['write']
format = data['format']
def camera():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

The above code throws an error

```
File "room-out.py", line 14, in camera
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)
TypeError: Argument 'index' is required to be an integer.
```

Is there a way load stream dynamically so I don't have to edit the code over and over again to open the stream.

Comment: `print(repr(camera))` please

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz <function camera at 0x000002120E5E7160> This is what I get when I print  `print(repr(camera))`

Answer (score 1):

Camera declared as variable and function were conflicting. Just renamed the variable camera to cam in line 4. It worked.